# Is it possible to deduce that the limit $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lambda(n)\frac{x^n}{\Gamma(n)}$ is finite?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, gamma-function, liouville-function

Let $\lambda(n)$ for integers $n\geq 1$ the Liouville function, see its definition for example from this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_function). And we denote with $\Gamma(n)$ the particular values of the gamma function over positive integers $n\geq 1$, thus it is $(n-1)!$.

We consider $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lambda(n)\frac{x^n}{\Gamma(n)}.\tag{1}$$
(Notice that is the limit of previous series as $x$ tends to $-\infty$).

> **Question.** Is it possible to deduce that $(1)$ is finite? **Many thanks.**

Comment: I hope that my question has mathematical meaning. I would like if it is possible to deduce that our limit is finite, is infinite or well oscillates. Many thanks all users.

Comment: Let $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\lambda(n)\frac{(-1)^n x^n}{\Gamma(n)}$. We have
$$ g(s)= (\mathcal{L} f)(s) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n\lambda(n) (-1)^n}{s^{n+1}} $$
and if we manage to prove that $\lim_{s\to 0^+} g(s)<0$ we have that $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to +\infty$, since $f$ decays like $e^{-\lambda x}$ for some $\lambda>0$. If there is something known about the partial sums of $n\lambda(n)$ or $n\lambda(n)(-1)^n$, this is a good moment for exploiting it through summation by parts. It does not look to be a simple problem, anyway.

Comment: Many thanks, one more time my problem has no more context (and my thougths were that maybe could have a suitable answer for the question), but it is good have your reasonings that I am going to read. I hope that other users want to do feedback about the question @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: I promise a live goose as added prize for the first user solving this problem! (Not, it is a joke, in fact now I've no much money and each goose that I am  meeting doesn't know how to fly yet.)

Comment: I would also add that [this answer of Peter Humphries on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/14233/30521), together with my previous remark, points towards a positive answer to your conjecture, since it shows that $L(n)$ is predominantly negative.

Comment: I'm going to read the post @JackD'Aurizio

Answer (score 1):

Definitely too long for a comment.

Let $L(n)=\sum_{m)=1}^{n}\lambda(m)$. Quoting [Peter Humphries from MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/14233/30521):

> As for somewhat elementary methods (in the sense of avoiding the Riemann zeta function) to show that $L(n)$ is "usually" of order $\sqrt{n}$, one can use the Lambert series
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\lambda(n)q^n}{1-q^n}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{q^{n^2}}.$$
>   As
>   $$\frac{q^n}{1+q^n} = \frac{q^n}{1-q^n} - 2\frac{q^{2n}}{1-q^{2n}},$$
>   we have
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\lambda(n)}{q^{-n}+1}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{q^{n^2}} - 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{q^{2n^2}}$$
>   or equivalently, letting $q = e^{-\pi/x}$ and $\psi(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{e^{-\pi xn^2}}$, where $x$ is large,
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\lambda(n)}{e^{n\pi/x}+1}} = \psi(1/x) - 2\psi(2/x)$$
>   Now $\psi(x)$ satisfies the functional equation
>   $$\frac{1+2\psi(x)}{1+2\psi(1/x)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}},$$
>   and so we can rewrite this as
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\lambda(n)}{e^{n\pi/x}+1}} = \frac{1-\sqrt{2}}{2}\sqrt{x} + \frac{1}{2} + (\psi(x)-2\psi(x/2))\sqrt{x}.$$
>   For large $x$, the left-hand side "looks like" $L(x)$, whereas the right-hand side is dominated by the term $\frac{1-\sqrt{2}}{2}\sqrt{x}$. This also explains why $L(n)$ is predominantly negative, as $\frac{1-\sqrt{2}}{2}$ is negative.

Now comes my comment under the main thread (with a $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ addendum):

> Let $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\lambda(n)\frac{(-1)^n x^n}{\Gamma(n)}$. We have
>   $$ g(s)= (\mathcal{L} f)(s) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n\lambda(n) (-1)^n}{s^{n+1}} =\color{blue}{-\frac{d}{ds}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\lambda(n)(-1)^n}{s^n}}$$
>   and if we manage to prove that $\lim_{s\to 0^+} g(s)<0$ we have that $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to +\infty$, since $f$ decays like $e^{-\lambda x}$ for some $\lambda>0$. If there is something known about the partial sums of $n\lambda(n)$ or $n\lambda(n)(-1)^n$, this is a good moment for exploiting it through summation by parts. It does not look to be a simple problem, anyway.

Not a simple problem, indeed, but to remark the connection between $\mathcal{L} f$ and the Jacobi $\Theta$ function/[the Jacobi triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product) is enlightening. We have
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\lambda(n)(-1)^n}{s^n} = -\sum_{\substack{n\geq 1\\ n\text{ odd}}}\left(\frac{\lambda(n)}{s^n}+\frac{\lambda(n)}{s^{2n}}-\frac{\lambda(n)}{s^{4n}}+\frac{\lambda(n)}{s^{8n}}-\ldots\right)$$
and by setting $s=e^{\pi/x}$ (for $x\to +\infty$) the behaviour of the RHS (and its derivative) in a right neighbourhood of $s=0$ can be studied through Humphries' functional equation. I still have to complete the the necessary estimations in full rigor, but this points towards an affirmative answer to your question.

Comment: You take great dedication in your answers, many thanks today I am going to study your answer and Humphries' result.