# Is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n)\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{n!}}$ positive for $0<x<1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, mobius-function

Let $\mu(n)$ the Möbius function, see it you need this [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) And here $n!$ is the factorial.

After I've known a similar question from MathOverflow, I would like to know if it is possible to deduce something about the question that I've created.

> **Question.** Is $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n)\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{n!}}\tag{1}$$ positive, when $0<x<1$? **Many thanks.**

If my question was in the literature answer this question as a reference request, and I try to search and read those calculations.

My belief from my calculations using [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)  (it is as a toy model of previous function in $(1)$) is that our function has a root in the unit interval, see it with this code

`plot sum mu(n)/sqrt(n!) x^n, from n=1 to 1000, for 0<x<1`

Comment: The MathOverflow post is [**this**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84958/is-sum-limits-n-0-infty-xn-sqrtn-positive).

Comment: It looks like a reasonable conjecture, since $\sqrt{n!}\to +\infty$ rapidly. Have you tried to exploit the ideas outlined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2530835/is-it-possible-to-deduce-that-the-limit-lim-x-to-infty-sum-n-1-infty-lam) ? More important: *why* $\frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt{n!}}$ is a relevant weight?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I just found this comment, it was lost in time.